# Possible to capture the returned value from a Python list comprehension for use a condition?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to construct a value in a list comprehension, but also filter on that value. For example:

```
[expensive_function(x) for x in generator where expensive_function(x) < 5]
```

I want to avoid calling `expensive_function` twice per iteration.

The `generator` may return an infinite series, and list comprehensions aren't lazily evaluated. So this wouldn't work:

```
[y in [expensive_function(x) for x in generator where expensive_function(x)] where y < 5]
```

I could write this another way, but it feels right for a list comprehension and I'm sure this is a common usage pattern (possible or not!).

Comment: Are any of the answers worthy of being accepted?  If not, what information are you still looking for?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mark this one. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: No problem.  Was hoping you just needed a reminder.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If `generator` may be infinite, you do not want to use a list comprehension.  And not everything has to be a one-liner.

```
def filtered_gen(gen):
    for item in gen:
        result = expensive_function(item)
        if result < 5:
            yield result
```

Comment: Should the last two occurrences of `item` be replaced by `result`?

Comment: +1 to this. You can use itertools and generator expressions, but this is much easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer the part of the question about how to capture intermediate results in a list comprehension for use in a condition, and ignore the question of a list comprehension built from an infinite generator (which obviously isn't going to work), just in case anyone looking for an answer to the question in the title comes here.

So, you have a list comprehension like this:

```
[expensive_function(x) for x in xrange(5) if expensive_function(x) % 2 == 0]
```

And you want to avoid calculating `expensive_function` twice when it passes your filter. Languages with more expressive comprehension syntax (Scala, Haskell, etc) allow you to simply assign names to expressions calculated from comprehension variables, which lets you do things like the following:

```
# NOT REAL PYTHON
[result for x in xrange(5) for result = expensive_function(x) if result % 2 == 0]
```

But you can easily emulate this by turning the assignment `result = expensive_function(x)` into another `for` iteration over a sequence of one element:

```
[result for x in xrange(5) for result in (expensive_function(x),) if result % 2 == 0]
```

And the proof:

```
>>> def expensive_function(x):
        print 'expensive_function({})'.format(x)
        return x + 10
>>> [expensive_function(x) for x in xrange(5) if expensive_function(x) % 2 == 0]
expensive_function(0)
expensive_function(0)
expensive_function(1)
expensive_function(2)
expensive_function(2)
expensive_function(3)
expensive_function(4)
expensive_function(4)
[10, 12, 14]
>>> [result for x in xrange(5) for result in (expensive_function(x),) if result % 2 == 0]
expensive_function(0)
expensive_function(1)
expensive_function(2)
expensive_function(3)
expensive_function(4)
[10, 12, 14]
```

Answer (score 2):

you should make 2 generator expressions:

```
ys_all = (expensive(x) for x in xs)
ys_filtered = (y for y in ys_all if y <5)
```

or

```
from itertools import imap, ifilter
ys = ifilter(lambda y : y < 5, imap(expensive, xs))
```

Comment: Nope. Not if `xs` is infinite. Sadly Python doesn't have Haskell list comprehensions. Something, somewhere, would blow up.

Comment: Yes! This is the best answer in my opinion! Could you maybe call them "generator comprehensions" instead of list comprehensions?

Answer (score 1):

**Warning** This is a bit convoluted but does the job. I will use an example to explain it.

Let say `expensive_function = math.sin`

`infinite generator = collections.count(0.1,0.1)`

then

```
[z for z in (y if y < 5 else next(iter([])) 
     for y in (math.sin(x) for x in itertools.count(0.1,0.1)))]
```

is

```
[0.09983341664682815,
 0.19866933079506122,
 0.2955202066613396,
 0.3894183423086505,
 0.479425538604203]
```

So your problem boils down to

```
[z for z in (y if y < 0.5 else next(iter([])) \
         for y in (expensive_function(x) for x in generator))]
```

The trick is to force a `StopIteration` from a generator and nothing elegant than `next(iter([]))`

Here `expensive_function` is only called once per iteration.

Extend the Infinite Generator with a Finite Generator, with the Stop Condition. 
As the generator won't allow `raise StopIteration`, we opt for a convoluted way i.e. `next(iter([]))`
And now you have a Finite Generator, which can be used in a List Comprehension

As OP was concerned with the application of the above method for a non-[monotonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) function here is a fictitious non-monotonic function

Expensive Non-Monotonic Function `f(x) = random.randint(1,100)*x`

Stop Condition = `< 7`

```
[z for z in (y if y < 7 else next(iter([])) for y in 
      (random.randint(1,10)*x for x in itertools.count(0.1,0.1)))]

[0.9,
 0.6000000000000001,
 1.8000000000000003,
 4.0,
 0.5,
 6.0,
 4.8999999999999995,
 3.1999999999999997,
 3.5999999999999996,
 5.999999999999999]
```

Btw: `sin` in true sense is non-monotonic over the entire range `(0,2pi)`

Comment: Crazy! This is subtly different, because `sin` is a non-monotonic function (I didn't say that `expensive_function` is monotonic, but it is!) and this halts **the first time** the condition is not true, not continuing **for all conditions** where the condition is true. That said, if it were non-monotonic, this would result in an infinite evaluation...

Comment: @Joe, This will work even for non-monotonic function. See my update